# How to get accesse to type variable outside its class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two classes `Player` and `GameScene`.

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
   init(name: SKSpriteNode) {
      // not important for my problem
      super.init(...)
   }
}
```

And this is the class, where `class Player` is used:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   var mySprite = SKSpriteNode()

   override didMove(to view: SKView) {
      let player = Player(name: mySprite)
      addChild(player)
    }

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      // I WANT TO CALL let player HERE BUT IT DOES NOT WORK
   }
```

Now I want to override `touchesBegan` function and make something happen whenever the player is touched. The problem is, that `player` is declared inside `didMove` function and `touchesBegan` cannot see it.

When I declade `player` globally, I can not insert the SKSpriteNode `mySprite` because it says:
"Use of unresolved identifier".

So how can I declare my variable `player` of type `Player` globally, so I have access in `touchesBegan` function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var mySprite = SKSpriteNode()
    var player: Player? //declaring your player Object

    override didMove(to view: SKView) {
        player = Player(name: mySprite) // initialize your player Object here
        addChild(player)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let player = self.player else { return }
        //now you can call your player Object here
    }
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! It worked, thank you so much. I doubted somebody would even get my answer...may I just ask what the line "guard let player = self.player else {return}" does? Do I need to code it aswell?

Comment: Because I used `var player: Player!` by force unwrapping it meaning it will crash if it becomes `nil` , with guard I just assure that if for some reason becomes nil the process wont crash. You can declare it as `var player: Player?` which I think its better and in guard unwrap it.